# Why is my crystal oscillator (4 pin DIP 4 MHz unbranded from ebay) producing unusable clock signal waves?

Tags: hardware, 8-bit-microcomputers

I was trying to make a Z80 computer (I tried with Intel 8088 and failed because I am dumb) so I bought a 4-pin 4 MHz crystal(from here:[ebay listing](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/233688868096?var=534104417810&hash=item3668f12500:g:zTwAAOSwiOlkEz%7En&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4Oq4vMMsMAe%2F%2FyhSuradB7f5ksj7G6oHUaQCRH7lfzb0xqjvQTUeRhQBgB0Z7imQpnvAPtsXgA8ECAL4FSd9qckDX6PDb8NlNq7nIdbjnExgothtQntIZ4W4dXrXfyOCMfW%2BqaSz4Fhov6tVfVtWRjqvdz1sCzWVUmLebIHH6sBDZCAfx3DbeYaJ6f%2Bh%2F6utCBCGdDZbcxT92Rw5f27O5EeKAKputqOBgxbX%2BO3Stw4OgKJajafnOKZ91LyJIIEMlwlYcMIqzpXeKA2rBPFUnSSrU4Vokg16EGJovLEtNHdv%7Ctkp%3ABFBMmuKyqu5i)) and I tried to check the crystal by connecting it like this:

[image: Schematic]

Iam pretty sure the fourth pin is unused as there isn't a change in behaviour whether I connect it to ground or VCC.

It produced these unusable clock signals that were always high and never went low.(on 1X:Vmax:2.65-2.75 Vmin:1.65-1.95)

On 10X(50V):Vmax:26.50V Vmin:20.50

I powered the crystal with a 5V Arduino mega and measured the crystal with a made-in-China oscilloscope which apparently when connected to nothing, will show Vmin:0.35V Vmax:0.20 which doesn't make sense so the oscilloscope might not be entirely accurate.

I tried connecting the crystal to a Z80A, but it didn't work.

Here is a link to a recording of what I am talking about: [the recording](https://imgur.com/263qFZ5)

Comment: You don't say what the model of the crystal is. Have you checked the data sheet (for typical application)? Sometimes the fourth pin is used to enable the device. Is a load required? Is your probe set to x10 (that might help)? Please [edit] and update your question.

Comment: Are you sure you got a 5V type? There's also types out there that want 3.3 Volts

Comment: This is an electronics question.  But I suspect you don't make an oscillator by just connecting a crystal to DC.  Or is the thing you bought more than just 'a crystal'?

Comment: Unless this is an all in one unit, you'll need additional components. depending on setup at least two capacitors or an inverter and a resistor, or two inverters and a capacitor ... or ... or. To use it with a Z80 it might be best to start by checking the [Z80](https://archive.org/details/Zilog_Z80-CPU_Technical_Manual/page/n61/mode/2up) manuals :))

Comment: See [Can I get a clock signal from a 4-pin crystal oscillator circuit by applying 5V to the input pin?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/629540/64015). It may not be a crystal oscillator but just a crystal instead - as Raffzahn states above.

Comment: Very likely your "cheap Chinese oscilloscope" will have a bandwidth somewhere in the low-MHz (or even below) range and not be capable of properly seeing a 4 MHz signal.

Comment: "I tried [...] and failed because I am dumb" - this bothers me.  Don't confuse inexperienced with dumb.  The best rule when learning anything new is to "fail, and fail often".  Every failure is simply finding out what doesn't work.  Keep going.

Comment: @Geo... - "Only make new mistakes" is good too.

Comment: I’d suggest moving this to SE Electronics but I suspect you’d get the stock ‘show us the datasheet’ response.  This https://www.opel.ece.vt.edu/reference/DataSheets/MCO-1510A-szgreat.pdf may be the datasheet for the part, and suggests you may have the enable pin floating.

Comment: @Frog unfortunately no, i have tried to connect the bottom left pin to ground and VCC it doesn't change anything

Comment: @DragoniteBrian1024 **Again, that's not an RC.SE question, but basic electronics and should be moved over there**. That said. An oscillator does not provide a ready measurable signal. It needs to work via a load for analogue application, like a 50 ohm resistor between Out and Ground (8/7). A oscilloscope does NOT provide a load - after all it's made to interfere as little as possible. For digital use it needs to be coupled by a small capacitor (optional but never a bad idea) instead and then rectified using some digital circuit. In the old days one often used a basic 7400 element.

Comment: @DragoniteBrian1024 See [this drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7mVL.png) for a typical test situation using a 15 pf capacitor (or 50 Ohm resistor) - and a connection between Pin 1 and GND, as that may be needed to enable the device.

Comment: @Raffzahn That's wrong. That is a crystal oscillator module, and it will, when powered, output a square wave measurable directly with an oscilloscope. It does not need special loading. The oscillator may be damaged or the used scope may have low bandwidth so it can't show the waveform. Probes do load the circuit already, 1x probes have very high capacitive load with multiple tens of pF and 1 Mohm which will limit bandwidth enough to be unusable, 10x probes are much better and have just around 20pF and 10 Mohm of load so much higher bandwidth. For most modules like this, 50 ohms too much!

Comment: This question belongs in Electrical Engineering. @Justme is correct about CRO probes. The issue I have with this question is the +5V supply. On what basis is +5V appropriate? If this was a low voltage module the device may have been damaged.